# Stanford Core NLP Tree Parser Sentence Limits wrong - suggestions?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, parse-tree

I'm dealing with *german* law documents and would like to generate parse trees for sentences. I could find and use Standford [CoreNLP Parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.html). However, it does not recognize sentence limits as good as other tools (e.g. spaCy) when parsing the sentences of a document. For example, it would break sentences at every single '.'-character, incl. the dot at the end of abbreviations such as "incl.")
Since it is crucial to cover the whole sentence for creating syntax trees, this does not really work out for me.

I would appreciate any suggestions to tackle this problem, espacially pointers to other software that might be better suited for my problem. If I overlooked the possibility to tweak the Stanford parser, I would be very grateful for any hints on how to make it better detect sentence limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick glance into the docs did the trick: You can run your pipeline, which might include the [sentence splitter](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/corenlp-docs-dev/ssplit.html), with the attribute
`ssplit.isOneSentence = true` to basically disable it. This means you can split the sentences beforehand, e.g. using spaCy, and then feed single sentences into the pipeline.